# Keep body bg fixed while child elements scroll

Tags: html, css

So you'll see in my example, I have a gradient applied to `html` and a texture overlay .png on `body` which at first looks as expected.

I added a div with a large height to show my issue. Notice as you scroll down in the example you see the `div` overflow `body` and the texture overlay applied to `body` gets cut and almost has a parallax effect.

What I want is the html/body backgrounds to stay fixed so the content of body will scroll over them as expected while the gradient and overlay stay stationary and the size of the window. I'm thinking you'll notice what I'm talking about pretty easily with the example.

What am I missing here?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  background: radial-gradient(#bcd197, #325757);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
  outline: blue 3px dashed;
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/NFvCfrj/texture.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

div {
  outline: red 3px dashed;
  height: 200rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `body`'s height to `100%`, so the background no longer render below the initial viewport height.

You must set the same div height to the body or mark body height to `auto` (default value).

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

html {
  background: radial-gradient(#bcd197, #325757);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
  outline: blue 3px dashed;
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/NFvCfrj/texture.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

div {
  outline: red 3px dashed;
  height: 200rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```